# Динамическая  строка. Проблемы ввода-вывода

Tags: массивы, указатели, c++, строки

Про вводе строки вывод обрывается перед символом пробела.
Как этого избежать?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <clocale>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

void string_in (char **str)
{
    *str=new char [];
    cin>>*str;
}
int main ()
{
    setlocale (0,"");
    char *str;
    string_in(&str);
        cout<<str;
    getch();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: >С++: Динамический символьный массив
>`*str=new char [];`
>вводе строки

Я чего-то не понял?

Comment: `#include <conio.h>`, омфг.

Comment: @VladD Любят в вузах ms dos. Ой как любят.

Answer (score 3):

На C++ не пользуйтесь ручным управлением памятью, пользуйтесь функцией [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline):

```
void string_in(std::string& str)
{
    std::getline(std::cin, str);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте `getline`

[std::istream::getline](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/getline/) <-- там есть пример кода

Comment: @fogbit: на C++ лучше пользоваться подходящими языку строками всё же.

Answer (score 0):

Функция ждёт массив стрингов, а получает адрес одного стринга, который ещё передаётся оператору new. Мой вам совет: не заморачивайтесь с указателями, а используйте `std::string` и `std::vector`:

```
void string_in(std::vector<std::string> mas_vt)
{
    if (mas_vt.empty()) return;
    …
}
```

Comment: @Airhand, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.